# maya python cmds.file(query = True, shortName = True) not working

Tags: python, maya

I noticed a strange thing in Maya. I would like to know if you guys got the same problem or if I am doing something wrong?

There is the cmds.file command. The documentation says it got a "shortName" flag which should return the currently opend scenename without the complete path.

```
cmds.file(query = True, shortName = True)

# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 1: Flag cannot be queried. #
```

Also the doc. says that shortName is a queryable flag.

I also tried to just use the sceneName flag which should return the complete path of the currently opend file. Which indeed it does. But when I set it to "False" it gives me the same error you saw above.

This happens on Maya 2016 and Maya 2017.

The doc: http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/file.html#flagshortName

Thanks for reading and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you tried the command in the right way, but what the documentation says is:

> When used with a **main query flag** it indicates that the file name returned will be the short name

So, in this situation the main query flag could be `sceneName` and then the `shortName` can be specified, to get just the filename.

```
import maya

print maya.cmds.file(query=True, sceneName=True, shortName=True)
```

Anyway, if you want to have a little more control over the specific path manipulation, may I suggest you to use the python [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module? Or even better the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module?

Comment: Oh damn.. Thanks for pointing that out.. Yeah i did it with the os.path but I will replace the whole file path handeling with regular expression